# Regex select a (-) but ignore the selection if it is inside certain words (start-up|stop-off)

Tags: php, regex

I want to select and replace the dashes/hyphens ("-") with spaces (" ") in certain words (ex: "start-down" changes to "start down"), while ignoring the replace for other words (ex: "start-up" stays "start-up") using the PHP's preg_replace().

This is the regex that I have come up with:

> `(?<!(start))-(?!(up))|(?<!(start))-|-(?!(up))`

Using the above regex on this data:

> 1. start-up
> 2. start-off
> 3. anything-up
> 4. stop-off
> 5. start-off
> 6. stop-up

Returns the following:

> 1. start-up
> 2. start down
> 3. anything up
> 4. stop off
> 5. start off
> 6. stop up

It works perfectly for start-up.  But I know down the road I'll need to add other exceptions to the list such as stop-off (ex: "stop-off" stays "stop-off").

So the question is this: 
Should I do it via PHP's function, such as str_replace() and if else/switch case with an array of "unchangeable" words, loop through those and make appropriate changes if necessary or is there a way in regex to ignore some select if the select is part inside a certain word?

Comment: Is this going to be used on a large string of text, or any array of words?

Comment: It will be used on words like the list, not more than 3-4 words at the most I would say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pattern reset (`\K`) trick with preg_replace, example:

```
$input = 'passe-montagne, passe-partout, passe-murail, start-up, stop-off';

echo preg_replace('~\b(?>start-up|stop-off)\b\K|-~', ' ', $input);
```

All that is before `\K` is checked but excluded from the match result.

Notice: your pattern can be more efficient with this kind of tricks:

```
~\bst(?>art-up|op-off)\b\K|-~
```

Comment: It seems `\K` is not supported by .NET (my current primary platform) and was only recently added to PHP. +1 I learned something new today.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: indead, you can find it too in perl, but not in ruby or python as far i know.

Answer (score 3):

My php is a bit rusty, but here's what I'd suggest:

```
function do_replace($m) {
    return strlen($m[1]) > 0 ? $m[1] : ' ';
}

preg_replace_callback('/(start-up|stop-off)|-/', 'do_replace', $input);
```

If your version of PHP supports [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), you can do this:

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '/(start-up|stop-off)|-/',
    function($m) {
        return strlen($m[1]) > 0 ? $m[1] : ' ';
    },
    $input
);
```

The real benefit of this method is that it's very easy to extend to any number of 'special words' that you want to exclude.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought about doing a preg_replace_callback().  But I'll go with Casimir et Hippolyte's answer since it will be easier to implement in my app.